# changing value in IF statement after emit is finished and not before the emit

Tags: javascript, socket.io

What I want achieve here is when the `IF` statement is `true` the `fightID` changes to some other value so it won't match the value that it was assigned before so I couldn't run the `win-fight` emit through console straight away when the fight is finished. But all I get is `Bad id` right now so it won't even run the `win-fight` emit. How can I solve this ?

```
var uuid = uuid4();

        socket.on('attack', () => {

        var fightID = uuid;

        if(enemyHealth === 0 && uuid4.valid(uuid) === fightID|| userHealth === 0 
        && enemyHealth === 0 && uuid4.valid(uuid) === fightID) {

          fightID = 185;

         socket.emit('win-fight'); // next emit
       } else {
         console.log('Bad id');
       }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the issue should be resolved by making the following adjustment:

```
var uuid = uuid4();

var isFightFinished = false;

// Declare fightID here
var fightID = uuid;

    socket.on('attack', () => {
    // Remove fightID from here
    // var fightID = uuid;

    if(isFightFinished === false && (enemyHealth <= 0 || userHealth <= 0)) {

      // Now you're newly assigned fightID is remembered for the next attack 
      // event
      fightID = 185;

      isFightFinished = true;

     socket.emit('win-fight'); // next emit
   } else {
     console.log('Bad id');
   }

});
```

Comment: When players hp is zero I still get `Bad id` ant it's not emiting `win-fight`

Comment: Well this works. But then again if I don't check if fightID is valid or not I can multiply times run `win-fight` through console when both players hp goes to zero. :)

Comment: Works again, but it's really strange that even after the fight is finished (one of the player hp is zero) without refreshed the page I still can run successfuly `win-fight` emit through console. Maybe I should emit something from client side.

Comment: Perhaps this update is a better, more reliable approach?

Comment: Still. It works when user hp is more than zero. But even when hp goes to zero the value changes to `true` and still can multiple times run win-fight. Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Works. I just placed IF to `win-fight` socket and then made logic here :)